# Updating collection-based Widget RemoteViews after AsyncTask callback

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-widget, kotlin

I'm in a situation where the elements of my Widget's ListView are reliant on content fetched over the network via an AsyncTask. The code for getViewAt in my RemoteViewsFactory implementation is as follows:

```
val preRendered = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.list_item_layout)

MyAsyncTask(preRendered).execute()

return preRendered
```

And the AsyncTask is defined as an inner class

```
private inner class MyAsyncTask(val remoteViews: RemoteViews) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>()
{
    override fun doInBackground(vararg nothing: Void): Bitmap = <fetch image from internet synchronously>

    override fun onPostExecute(result: Bitmap) = remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageview, result)
}
```

My basic train of thought is that I should perform the rendering of some default layout to the RemoteViews and return that to be inserted into the list, then allow the network operations to take place in the background. I then make modifications in the onPostExecute method of the AsyncTask on the same instance of RemoteViews, which I believe should in theory result in the actual list element being updated. However, despite the onPostExecute being run and the view being populated with its initial layout, the image is never set. Does anybody have any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Afterthought: I've tried just using a TextView and setting some static text in the AsyncTask and that also does not work.

Comment: is the textview also part of the list item layout?  if so, you might need to call `invalidateViews` on the list.

Comment: What would I call invalidateViews on? The whole architecture of having a RemoteViewsService that supplies a RemoteViewsFactoryAdapter has me fairly confused about what part of the system needs to be notified of the update to invalidate the row.

Comment: On the list.  Your widget has a `getViewAt` returning a view for a specific item.  After updating `remoteViews`, invalidate the list view.  See if that helps or changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `ListView` and `ArrayAdapter`.  [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) is a link to one good tutorial on the subject.

The idea is that you have your background task update backing data rather than your view directly.  The backing data is a collection of items representing the data for each item in your list.  Your `AsyncTask` would do it's thing and update the item in the collection.  Then it would call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `ArrayAdapter` to get it to update the `ListView`.